# Package pgf Error: No shape named X is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, nodes

I can't get this document to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line join=bevel,]

  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (140.1bp,19bp) node {310e} edge [loop below]  ();
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (28bp,55.424bp) node {311r} edge [loop left]  ();

%

%%circles around nodes
%31-, 310e and 311r
%fail here
\draw (311r) -- (310e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
%
```

It fails when I add that last draw command, saying `Package pgf Error: No shape named 311r is known.`, and another with "310e" instead of "311r". I just need to be able to draw lines with nodes as the anchors. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `... node (310e) {} ...` instead. Note the round brackets and braces.

Comment: yes you forgot to name the nodes

Comment: @Altermundus: Please write up an answer for this, since I lack the `tikz` skill to do it properly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As said in comments you have to name the nodes, this means all you need to is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line join=bevel,]

    \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
    \draw (140.1bp,19bp) node(310e) {310e} edge [loop below]  ();
    \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
    \draw (28bp,55.424bp) node(311r) {311r} edge [loop left]  ();

    %%circles around nodes
    %31-, 310e and 311r
    %fail here
    \draw (311r) -- (310e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Anyway, your code looks interesting, because of the unnecessary `pgfsetstrokecolor`, `definecolor` and the exact positions. Are you sure you need them? Maybe `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` will help you (**16.5.3 Advanced Placement Options** in the [`tikz`/`pgf` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)).

Comment: The code was generated by dot2tex[http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/], and I had a hard time following it myself. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You will get much better results (code and output) if you take a look at the [tikz/pgf manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf). The manual is really good.

Comment: It looks quite good, but it's 700 pages... Do you know of a condensed one?